# Is the current path `.` in the classpath by default?

Tags: java, ubuntu

Do the second command add the current path as another path for searching?

```
javac -cp /home/tim/program_files/programming/java/junit-4.11.jar MyTest.java

javac -cp .:/home/tim/program_files/programming/java/junit-4.11.jar MyTest.java
```

Is it the correct way to separate multiple paths, by a colon?

Isn't the current path always in ClassPath by default, and thus no need to explicitly specify?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From Oracle's [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) on setting the class path:

> The default class path is the current directory. Setting the CLASSPATH variable or using the `-classpath` command-line option **overrides** that default, so if you want to include the current directory in the search path, you must include "." in the new settings.

Use `;` for Windows and `:` for Unix-like operating systems as a separator for multiple paths.

Answer (score 8):

If you add classpath then current path is **omitted**, which is a very very **unpleasant** and **unexpected** behavior :(

Moreover to add current path I found (at least for ubuntu) that **IT IS NOT ENOUGH** to add `.` in classpath but you have to add `./*`

For example (this **will not** work)

`java -ea -cp ".:lib/*" org.testng.TestNG suites/regression.xml`

will **NOT** work if you have a jar file in current path

the correct one is

`java -ea -cp "./*:lib/*" org.testng.TestNG suites/regression.xml`

I hope no one shoots himself or have a heart attack!

Comment: "the correct one is `java -ea -cp "./*" ...`" was my saving grace. The default won't even give you the expected behavior for Scala 3.2.2. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

From [the help page (FOR WINDOWS)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html):

> ```
> -classpath classpath
> -cp classpath
>
>     Specifies a list of directories, JAR files, and ZIP archives to
>     search for class files. Separate class path entries with semicolons
>     (;). Specifying -classpath or -cp overrides any setting of the
>     CLASSPATH environment variable.
>
>     If -classpath and -cp are not used and CLASSPATH is not set, then the
>     user class path consists of the current directory (.).
> ```

Note that, on windows, the path separator is a `;` semicolon.

On other platforms the separator is the colon `:`.

This conforms with the standard path-like systems on the various platforms.

Answer (score 4):

> Do the second command add the current path as another path for searching?

Yes

> Is it the correct way to separate multiple paths, by a colon?

depends on platform, in unix platform `:` works, in windows you need `;`

> Isn't the current path always in ClassPath by default, and thus no need to explicitly specify?

Current directory is present by default unless you override it with `-cp` in first case it is not present in second case it is

Answer (score 0):

> Solution: Just **delete environment variable "CLASSPATH"**, and then **restart your terminal** (command prompt)

- Explaining: Once you will remove then it will use it's (CLASSPATH) default value, for more information you can take reference from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)