# How to set classpath for current directory in Java?

Tags: java

How can I include current folder as classpath? I got a Utility and a Main class like;

```
/home/project/Main.class
/home/project/libs/com/fr/Utility.class
```

When I try to run Main class as(under /home/project/ dir);

```
java -cp "libs/*;" Main
```

I am getting below error.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

**EDIT:**

Main class;

```
import com.fr.Utility;

public class Main{
 ....
}
```

Utility class;

```
package com.fr;

public class Utility{
 ....
}
```

When I run;

```
java -cp .:libs/* Main
```

I am getting below error;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fr/Utility
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fr.Utility
```

Comment: your current directory ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use colon as the path separator `:` if you are on Linux, `;` if on Windows.

Also include the current path with a dot `.` and remove the wildcard `*` from the classpath:

`java -cp .:libs/ Main` or `java -cp .;libs/ Main`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26246470/8063451) and also the "Understanding class path wildcards" section in [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

Comment: When I run your command I am getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fr/Utility"

Comment: @hellzone Try remove the wildcard from libs/*

Comment: "java -cp .:libs Main" just worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Use `.` for current folder:

```
java -cp .;libs/ Main
```

Comment: an explanation would be better for the answer

Comment: Still getting same error.

Comment: On Linux or macOS, use `:` (colon) instead of `;` (semi-colon) as the path separator.

Answer (score 1):

Try out

```
java -cp .;libs/ Main
```

The main issues are probably:

1. Current classpath is not included by default in custom classpaths
2. Classpath entries containing * will not match .class files, and will also not recursively search subdirectories.