# Error: Could not find or load main class CountRows?

Tags: java

**Please suggest How can I improve my question**

I ran my code but it throws cannot find main class error. I know this error comes when name of class with main method is different from file name. I tried to solve this error for an hour. I need help.

**CountRows.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class CountRows
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Count number of rows in a specific table!");
        Connection con = null;
        int count = 0;
        try
        {
            //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jdbctutorial","root","dics");    
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Execution**

```
 >javac -classpath "e:\softwares\java\jar files\mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar" CountRows.java

 E:\user\java\jdbc\test>java -classpath "e:\softwares\java\jar files\mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar" CountRows

Error: Could not find or load main class CountRows
```

**Edit: Although the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122074/11498860) works but I still don't understand what was wrong with my way of executing code**

Comment: Where's the error in the execution?

Comment: I have edited my question @AzizSonawalla

Comment: One option is `E:\>cd "e:\softwares\java\jar files"` and then `E:\softwares\java\jar files\>java -cp mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar CountRows`

Comment: Although your solution worked. I don't understand what was wrong with my way. I should have worked. @ArvindKumarAvinash

Comment: I still don't understand what was wrong with my way of executing code. @ArvindKumarAvinash

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the current path \`.\` in the classpath by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246436/is-the-current-path-in-the-classpath-by-default)

Comment: @Progman I am posting an answer. I forgot to put semicolon in the java -classpath "classpath;" programName. It suggest that one should add semicolon in the classpath if there are multiple classpaths. I think my question will help future users. I will delete if say otherwise. Please help. should I delete this question or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Code is working perfectly fine there is no issue in it.

[image]

I suggest you set classpath initially before using `javac` and `java` tools.

Set your classpath via CMD

```
set classpath="<EXTERNAL_JAR_FILES_PATH>"
```

I hope this might help you. If you are still facing the same issue you can ping me back. I will be happy to help you.

Comment: Just use to run your code-- java CountRows

Comment: I still don't understand what was wrong with my way of executing code.