# `java myClass` not finding a .class file when `java myClass.java` does? (OpenJDK)

Tags: java

When I'm running `java -cp foo.jar MyClass` I keep getting the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class PrimVsKruskal
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PrimVsKruskal
```

But when I run `java -cp foo.jar MyClass.java` it works fine. This has been happening in different files in different directories and yes, I have run `javac -cp foo.jar MyClass.java` to generate the .class bytecode.

I've also tried running `java -cp foo.jar MyClass.class` (same error but with '.class' at the end of each line) and have become fairly certain I just don't understand the `java` command very well. When I delete the MyClass.class file and run `java -cp foo.jar MyClass.java` it runs fine which seems to suggest that `java` is compiling its own bytecode when run with a .java file rather than just interpreting the bytecode. Is this true?

Any help with this, or just a better understanding of the `java` than what I can glean from the man pages would be very much appreciated! I've searched around online but when I have to search "java command" nothing relevant has come up.

Not sure if it matters, but I'm running `OpenJDK version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14` on Ubuntu 18.04.4.

Thanks!

============

Edit due to comment:

The .jar file is algs4.jar from https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/. A minimum working example that is giving me these same errors is:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.*;

public class MyClass{

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println( "I am working! ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a Manifest file in your JAR?

What does you class declaration look like in your .java file:

public class MyClass      ???

Do you have a module file? 
Does it work when you have a Jar that contains ONLY a single .class file in it?

Comment: @AminM I'm working with the .jar file from here: https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/ so I'm assuming it's well set up (I don't really get Manifests but happy to go try to figure them out if you the solution lies in that direction). My class is outside that .jar. Give me a few minutes and I'll edit in a minimal working example of my class declaration. Thanks.

Comment: Ok.. if you class is outside the jar then its simpler.

What is your classes name inside the .java file?

Comment: @AminM Updated the answer with a minimum working example.

Comment: Maybe I should add that its not giving me any issues with using classes from the .jar file.

Comment: see my answer below.. I think that's the cause of your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you include the **-cp** option you are overriding the class path.

So if your .class file is in the current path you must write:

```
// Linux or MacOS
java -cp ".:foo.jar" MyClass

// Windows
java -cp ".;foo.jar" MyClass
```

Related article: [Is the current path `.` in the classpath by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246436/is-the-current-path-in-the-classpath-by-default)